# Javascript How to use Async/Await with a mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to query my mysql database for a value using Async/Await but my constant 'map' always returns undefined, I am not too sure why

```
const get_map = () =>{
    db.query('SELECT game,game2 FROM battles WHERE player1=? OR player2=?',[result.char,result.char],(err,results)=>{
        if(err){
            return(err)
        }
        if(!results[0]){
            return('No such battle?')
        }
        console.log(results[0])
        return(results[0])
    })
}
const proccessTurn = async ()=>{
    const map = await get_map()
    console.log(map)
    let game = JSON.parse(map.game)
    let game2 = JSON.parse(map.game2)
    const char = result.char
    const playerTurn = game2.turn[0]
}
```

The console doesn't even log

```
console.log(results[0])
```

This line so why does the await function resolve before it actually returns something? Shouldn't it wait for the returns?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Remove `{...}` from `get_map` or change it to `return db.query(...)` and it should work fine.

Comment: @ulou What is the problem and how does your suggestion solve it?

Comment: The problem is that he forgot about `return`, I think it's good enough explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter to `db.query()` is a callback. If you're returning anything in callback it's actually returned to the function itself, (db.query in this case). You're not returning anything from `get_map()`. So return a new promise from get_map like this,

```
const get_map = () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query('SELECT game,game2 FROM battles WHERE player1=? OR player2=?',[result.char,result.char],(err,results)=>{
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            }
            if(!results[0]){
                reject('No such battle?')
            }
            console.log(results[0])
            resolve(results[0])
        }
    });
}
const proccessTurn = async ()=>{
    const map = await get_map()
    console.log(map)
    let game = JSON.parse(map.game)
    let game2 = JSON.parse(map.game2)
    const char = result.char
    const playerTurn = game2.turn[0]
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

As the `mysql` library doesn't support promises, you can use the `promisify` util function from Node.js like this:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const query = promisify(db.query).bind(db);

const get_map = async () => {
    try {
         const result = await query('SELECT game,game2 FROM battles WHERE player1=? OR player2=?',[result.char,result.char]);
         if(!results[0]){
             return 'No such battle?';
         }
         console.log(results[0])
         return results[0];
    }
    catch(e) {
         return e;
    }
}
const proccessTurn = async ()=>{
    const map = await get_map()
    console.log(map)
    let game = JSON.parse(map.game)
    let game2 = JSON.parse(map.game2)
    const char = result.char
    const playerTurn = game2.turn[0]
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this out but it returns

```TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined```

Comment: It was a mistake in my code I replaced `.bind(db.query)` with `.bind(db)`. You should use this code rather than reinventing the wheel like the other answer suggests.

Comment: @GuerricP Returning a new promise is not re-inventing the wheel, I think. And by creating a new promise you can handle your biz specific edge cases in the same function.

Comment: Returning a promise is not reinventing the wheel, returning a promise **with our own code** is. The Node.js callback signature is a standard, `Promise` is a standard, that's why `promisify` exists.

Comment: @GuerricP Thank you very much this did work, however I am not too sure what is happening, would it be possible to get some explanation or a pointer to what to read to understand what is happening here if it isn't too much trouble. Thank you very much

Comment: @rauf543 historically Node.js handled asynchronism with a callback taking three parameters: `error`, `data` and `next`. The current trend is to use promises which highly helps write cleaner code, especially with `async`/`await` so they provided a native tool: `promisify` in order to facilitate the migration to the new promises pattern. It just takes a function which takes a Node.js callback as last parameter and transforms it in a function returning a `Promise`. Wrapping into a `Promise` with custom code is not advised, as this buit-in solution exists.